# Add one more cursor in VSCode extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-liveshare, text-cursor

I'm writing a Visual Studio Code extension that should be similar to Microsoft's Live Share extension.
One of the features that I would like to replicate from their extension is add one more cursor in VSCode extension for my viewers, which are connected and edit my code in the session.

I want to add a similar implementation :
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set the `editor.selections` to a complete array of ranges:

```
editor.selections = [ new vscode.Selection(2,0,4,5), new vscode.Selection(5,2,6,0)]
```

Comment: Yes, I did it, but how do I remove duplicate input from other cursors? And make only mine active?

Comment: @SergeyZaets You completely overrule any selections prior to this statement, no duplicates

Comment: @rioV8I need to display other user's cursors and simultaneously can write from mine. At the same time, so that there is no duplicate. Could you send me a sample code?

Comment: make a copy of the existing selections, add your selections, sort selections, determine overlap, remove overlap, set as new selection array